# What product is the Australian government Meteor made using?

Tags: government, tool-request, metadata, australia

> METeOR is Australia’s repository for national metadata standards for health, housing and community services statistics and information. - http://meteor.aihw.gov.au/

If I want to build a open data repository based with ISO 11179 is it possible with Meteor? Is the code for this available to work as a system on its alone?

Answer (score 2):

Based on http://meteor.aihw.gov.au/content/index.phtml/itemId/236643, which states *Synop Pty Ltd was awarded the contract to develop METeOR and developed the system by customising their XML-based content management system.*, I would say it is not free / open source software.

You could contact Synop, or you could ask AIHW if they can host some of your data: http://meteor.aihw.gov.au/content/index.phtml/itemId/276559